# What is involved with a perk test?

Tags: septic

We're looking at buying some land soon so we can build our little get away. I will have a perk test done at some point but was wondering what it involves? Is this something I could do on my own? I know it wouldn't be official but it would give me some indication as to whether or not it would pass. We are allowed to have a lagoon on the property so either way we will be purchasing before any test is done.

Answer (score 1):

A [percolation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percolation_test) is used to determine the absorption rate of the soil. Basically you'll dig a hole (or bunch of holes), put water in it (them), and time how long it takes for the water to go away.

It's probably not something you could do on a property you don't own, as it involves digging holes in somebody else's land. You could ask the seller if you can run the test, maybe they'll let you.

If you do run the test yourself. You'll have to check with the local government, to determine what they consider passing.

Comment: We will own the property soon and have plenty of time. I'll check with the local health department to see what they say since they're in charge of septic systems.